# Java HTML element reading

Tags: java, html

I am trying to create a java program that an detect changes in HTML elements on a web page. For example: http://timer.onlineclock.net/

With each passing second, the HTML elements of the clock change the source of the image they display. Is there anyway, using java, that I can EFFICIENTLY open a connection to this page, and be able to see when these elements change?

I have used HTMLUnit, but I decided that takes to long to load a page to be considered efficient enough.

The only way I know how to do it with a URL is to use a BufferedReader to read the page, and then use Regular Expressions to parse an HTML element within the source, but this would require me to "reload" the page every time that I want to see the properties of an element. Can anybody give me an suggetions on how I can detect these changes in a matter of milliseconds, without using much network resources?

Comment: If you want to parse HTML, it is best to use an existing HTML parser than to write your own. You cannot parse HTML using a regex (see http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html ). Perhaps a better question is what are you trying to do? Could you accomplish the same thing by treating the HTML like a text string and diffing 2 strings?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to learn and use javascript instead of server-side java. Javascript program runs on the client side (ie: the web browser) as opposed to the server side.

Typical HTML document consists of elements (eg: text, paragraph, list items etc). With javascript you can create timer, action user's event accordingly and manipulate those elements.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp is probably a good introduction to javascript, I suggest you spend some time on it

Answer (score 0):

The page in question appears to be a...Javascript digital clock.

If you want the current time, try `new Date();`.

If you want code to be called at a constant rate, try the `Timer` class. You can set a task to be called every second, which is the same frequency you will get by polling the page.

If you want to use the page as an external source of time, try the Network Time Protocol. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol It will provide much lower latency and is actually designed for this purpose.